# Ubuntu does not detect second Monitor anymore

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

I am using Ubuntu 16.4 along side windows 10 for couple of months on my DELL XPS l502x. it was working perfectly fine untill yesterday. After a long time i logged into Windows yesterday, afterwards Whenever i use ubuntu, it doesn’t recognize my second Monitor.
The other strange problem is that i can not change my graphic driver (in additional driver). When i select another driver, after applying changes, it goes back to the driver which was already in use.

Thanks for your help in advance

Regards, Mehrdad.

Comment: What is the Driver you are using? If you are not using 384 you can change the driver by `sudo apt-get install nvidia-384`.